# Iterating through Outlook email

Tags: python

I'm attempting to search through a specific inbox in Outlook by subject. However I want to correctly loop through the messages without causing any problems with Outlook crashing, etc. Is there better/safer way to do this?

```
email = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
your_folder = email.Folders.['Inbox']
messages = your_folder.Items
for i in range(3):
    for m in messages:
            if m.Subject == 'Email -' + date:
                items = m.Attachments
                number = items.Count
                x = 1
                if x <= number:
                    attachment = items.item(x)
                    break
    else:
        continue
    break
```